# Issue with frame closing Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I am having a issue with my frame switching after I click a button for my results. My button is hooked up to for inserting the fields into a database and it does do that but after it does it pulls the login screen back to the toplevel of the screen and just stay on the same screen how can I prevent this from happening? I am thinking its happening once the db closes. I don't get any errors.

```
if self.first == "":
    ms.showerror('Please enter a first name')
elif self.last == "":
    ms.showerror('Please enter a last name')
elif self.date == "":
    ms.showerror('Please enter a username')
elif self.addr == "":
    ms.showerror('Please enter a password')
elif self.phoneNum == "":
    ms.showerror('Please enter a password')
else:
    findSql = 'SELECT firstname, lastname FROM client WHERE firstname =? and 
    lastname=? '
c.execute(findSql, [(self.first),(self.last)])
    f = c.fetchall()
    if f:
        ms.showerror('User already exist')
    else:
        ms.showinfo('Account has been created')
        self.insert = 'INSERT INTO client(firstname, lastname, birthdate, 
    address, phone, symptom1, symptom2, symptom3, symptom4, symptom5) 
    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
c.execute(self.insert,[self.first, self.last, self.date, self.addr, 
    self.phoneNum, self.sym1, self.sym2, self.sym3, self.sym4, self.sym5])
db.commit()
db.close()
# runs calculation accuracy for random forest
a = Algo()
a.randomForest(self.master,self.Symptom1, self.Symptom2, self.Symptom3, self.Symptom4,self.Symptom5)
```

Comment: You forgot to fix the indentation of your code :( What is the window you expect to show up? Can you explain the behaviour more?

Comment: Im just trying for it save the records and show the user that the account was created. Once it shows created the user will stay on the same screen to view the results of all the information. But what is happening the frame moves to the back and the login screen appears.

Comment: Show us the names of frames and windows, you mean.